# Vectorized Implementation of Cox PH Model Scoring Process

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I created a Cox Survival model and for my purpose I need to use the mean instead of the median. In order to test the results of the model, I need to calculate a mean prediction for every record in my data. I am using R to accomplish this, and right now I am using a rather clunky for loop that takes too long to run.

Basically I am trying to find the area under the survival curve for every record, after adjusting the base survival curve to that specific record.

Psuedo Code:

```
area <- function(x, y) sum((y[-1]+y[-length(y)])/2*diff(x))
predictions = c()
for each record in the dataset
    new_surv = base_surv * e^(linear predictor for that record)
    area_under_curve = area(newsurv$time, newsurv$surv)
    predictions = c(predictions, area_under_curve)
end
```

I'd like to find a way to vectorize this (or another way to increase performance). It is made difficult by the fact I have to create a new_surv for every record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be the predicted restricted mean instead of the mean if the highest valued $Y$ is right-censored, but you can do this efficiently with

```
require(rms)
f <- cph(....)
M <- Mean(f)
M(linear predictor values)
```

`cph` is sort of a front-end for `coxph` in the `survival` package.